# Microsoft Teams Team creation automation via CVS file

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, microsoft-teams

Now the issue I'm having is with the Microsoft-Teams module `new-team -displayname $teamname` not recognizing my variable.

```
$teamname = Import-csv "C:\reports\teamscsv.csv" 
 | select -expand Team_Name
$owner = Import-csv "C:\reports\teamscsv.csv" 
 | select -expand Team_Owner
$team_descr = Import-csv "C:\reports\teamscsv.csv" 
 | select -expand Team_Description New-Team -displayname $teamname -description $team_descr
```

Error:

> New-Team : Cannot convert `System.Object[]` to the type `System.String` required by parameter `DisplayName`. Specified method is not supported.

```
$group = get-team
 | where {$_.DisplayName -like "$line.Team_Name"}
 | select -expand GroupID Add-TeamUser -GroupId $group -user $owner -role Owner
                                                                                                                                                                                           Error:
```

> Add-TeamUser: Cannot bind argument to parameter `GroupId` because it is null.

Answer (score 1):

We need to send team name as string, here is how we can do it using for loop.

```
$testcsv = import-csv D:\Microsoft\test.csv

 foreach($test in $testcsv)
 {
    $teamname = $test.Team_Name

    $owner =  $test.Team_Owner
    $team_descr =  $test.Team_Description  

    $group = New-Team -displayname $teamname -description $team_descr -AccessType "private"
    Write-Host ("My team name is: " + $teamname)
 }
```

Comment: My team name is: IT-Test-AutoCreation
My team name is: IT-Test-AutoCreation2
My team name is: IT-Test-AutoCreation3